# Transform two subtiles using sum and table summary in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, datatable

I have two lists such as ;

```
type1 0 0 0 0 0 2 5 5 5 1 1 3
type2 0 0 0 0 0 1 5 2 3 0 0 1
```

here is the dput format if it can helps:

```
list(type1 = c(0,0,0,0,0,2,5,5,5,1,1,3), 
     type2 = c(0,0,0,0,0,1,5,2,3,0,0,1))
```

And I would like to transform it in dataframe such as:

```
Nb type   Value
1  type1  2
2  type1  1
3  type1  1
4  type1  0
5+ type1  3
1  type2  0
2  type2  1
3  type2  1
4  type2  0
5+ type2  10
```

where `df$type==type1` corresponds of the number of `Nb` **1,2,3,4 or >=5**
and where  `df$type==type` corresponds of the number of sum of `Nb` **1,2,3,4 or >=5** of its correspondents in `type1` list.

---

For example:
in `type1` we see 3 numbers `>=5`, then I had the row:

```
Nb type   Value
5+ type1  3
```

, among those 3, I add the sum if `type2`, which is `5+2+3 = 10`, then I add:

```
Nb type   Value
5+ type1  3
5+ typ2   10
```

Does someone have an idea?

Comment: Do you have two lists or a single list with two veectors

Comment: It is a single list with two vectors called type1 and typ2, but I can easily split it into two independant lists.

Comment: What about the 0 values in the data

Comment: zeros do dot need to be take into account if there is zero in type1 and type2 equivalent

Comment: How did you get the 2 1 1 0 3 values

Comment: By using the equivalent of table(type1), there are ``2 values =1 ``, ``1 value = 2 ``, ```1 value =3```, and ```3 values >=5```

Comment: I guess my update would help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option is to get the `table` on the 'type1' element after converting to a `factor` with `levels` specified as 0 to 5, do a group by sum of 'type2' elements where the group is the 'type1' element, `stack` them into two column data.frame, and add the 'type' column as well and `rbind` the `list` elements

```
out <- do.call(rbind, Map(cbind, type = names(list1), lapply(setNames(list(table(factor(list1$type1, levels = 0:5)), tapply(list1$type2, factor(list1$type1, levels = 0:5), FUN = function(x) sum(x, na.rm = TRUE))), names(list1)), stack))
)
row.names(out) <- NULL
out$values[is.na(out$values)] <- 0
subset(out[c(3, 1, 2)], ind != 0)
```

-output

```
   ind  type values
2    1 type1      2
3    2 type1      1
4    3 type1      1
5    4 type1      0
6    5 type1      3
8    1 type2      0
9    2 type2      1
10   3 type2      1
11   4 type2      0
12   5 type2     10
```

---

Or using `forcats`

```
library(forcats)
library(dplyr)
grp <- factor(with(list1, fct_collapse(as.character(type1), 
       `>=5` = as.character(type1)[type1 >=5])), levels = c(0:4, ">=5"))
v1 <- table(grp)
v2 <- tapply(list1$type2, grp, FUN = sum)
bind_rows(list(type1 = stack(v1)[2:1], type2 = stack(v2)[2:1]), .id = 'type') %>% 
     filter(ind != '0')
```

Comment: Thanks but I do not get the same result as expected, Value for 5+ for instance should be 10, here it gives 1...